# Get model name instead of model id in openerp/odoo with onchange function

Tags: odoo, onchange

I am using openerp7. I have an on_change function which gives me back the model id. How can I get the name of the model?
Here is my code so far:

```python
_columns={
    'model': fields.many2one('ir.model', string='Models'),
    'model_name': fields.char('Model name')
}

def onchange_model(self, cr, uid, ids, model, context=None):
    print model #gives me back the id of the model(if i choose res.partner it gives me {int}73)
    # [...]
```

```xml
<field name="model_name" on_change="onchange(model)"/>
```

So my question is simple: How can I get the name of the model(for example res.partner).

Comment: You mean in python code? Just try `self._name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works (I didn't try it but it should work)

```python
ir_model_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model')
models_ids = ir_model_obj.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', model)])
for record in ir_model_obj.browse(cr, uid, models_ids, context=context):
    _logger.info(record.model) # You get the model here
    _logger.info(record.name) # You get the model name here
```

Comment: record.name gives me the name of the model.It is working.thnx

Comment: OK, you are welcome, I added another line with the model name to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For a more up to date version (V13)

The model name is

```py
print(self._name)
```

Which includes the module's name with the `module.model` notation. If you only want the model name, you need to do something like this:

```py
print(self._name.split('.', 1)[1])
```